# test fails to find files with processed path

Tags: files, test

I have backup of `/home/kuba/mp3` on external usb hard drive `/media/kuba/JCUBIC/mp3` and I move some files to different directories on usb drive and now I want to sync the files from usb to my home directory when I make the same thing with my other external usb drive I use this bash script:

```
find JCUBIC2/mp3/ | while read file; do
    test -e "${file/JCUBIC2/JCUBIC}" || (test -e "$file" && rm -r "$file" && echo $file);
done
```

I've try to do the same for `/home/kuba/mp3` with `sed` instead of bash substitution:

```
find ~/mp3/ -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do
    src=$(echo $file | sed -e 's%^/home/kuba%/media/kuba/JCUBIC%');
    test -e "$src" || (test -e "$file" && echo $src && echo $file);
done
```

(I replace `rm` with `echo` because I was testing if I get the correct path)

but I got echo path like this:

```
/media/kuba/JCUBIC/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 16.Problemy (g. Rubato).mp3
/home/kuba/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 16.Problemy (g. Rubato).mp3
/media/kuba/JCUBIC/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 07.Teksty.mp3
/home/kuba/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 07.Teksty.mp3
/media/kuba/JCUBIC/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 08.Marzenia (g. Grammatik).mp3
/home/kuba/mp3/[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 08.Marzenia (g. Grammatik).mp3
```

and `[Hip Hop]/Fenomen - Efekt` is on both directories and directory have the same size I didn't notice any difference in file names (if you press CTRL+F and paste `Fenomen - Efekt/Fenomen - 07.Teksty.mp3` both files will be highlighted by the browser), why it echo some files from that directory? What's wrong with my script?

Comment: Actually, I do not understand the problem description.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs somehow there are files that are on both directories and they are echo in second script, so something is wrong about it. It should show only files that are not in src and are in dest ($file)

Comment: I don't quite follow your reasoning: `$src` and `$file` are both file names. If the file named `$src` does not exist, `test -e "$src"` is `false` and the second part of the command will be executed. If the original file named `$file` exists (and it must, otherwise `find` would not have found it), then both file names are echoed.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs the second test is to prevent a case when I remove directory and If I try to remove a file in that directory, the find will find it but it will be removed with the directory, so I test if it's still there.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the issue correctly: You have checked that the files exist in both directories, but the command `test -e "$src"` still fails?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yes, it return false, so bash think that the file don't exist in `$src` and execute all stuff in parenthesis.

Comment: In that case, the question is not about `sed` or `find`. The question becomes: under which circumstances will `test -e` return `false` for a file that exists?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I didn't add `sed` or `find` tags it was the Jeff Schaller that edited the post.